# How to Register Pluggable Database(PDB) with new created LISTENER

Tags: oracle, listener, centos7, oracle19c, pluggable-database

I am working with `Oracle 19c` in `centos 7`. After Oracle installation, i created new **Container Database(CDB)** with **Plugguble Database(PDB)** using DBCA.

I am working with `port number=1522`

```
[oracle@ol8-19 ~]$ lsnrctl start LISTENER_TST

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 17-AUG-2020 16:02:02

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/Oracle19c/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/Oracle19c/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oraclebase19c/diag/tnslsnr/ol8-19/listener_tst/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT=1522)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT=1522)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_TST
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                17-AUG-2020 16:02:02
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 1 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/Oracle19c/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oraclebase19c/diag/tnslsnr/ol8-19/listener_tst/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT=1522)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

This is my **Listener.ora** file.

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

LISTENER_TST =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1522))
    )
  )
```

This is my **tnsnames.ora** file.

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))


LISTENER_ABC =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1522))

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

ABC =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ABC)
    )
  )
```

My pluggable Database name is PDB. How can i Register PDB with my listener with port 1522??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Connect to an idle instance and startup the instance

```
[oracle@ol8-19 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> startup;
```

change container to that pluggable database

```
SQL> alter session set container=pdb;
Session altered.
```

and open it

```
SQL> alter pluggable database pdb open;
```

Now, you set `local_listener`

```
SQL> alter system set local_listener='(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=ol8-19.localdomain)
(port=1522))' scope=spfile;

System altered.
```

and issue the following command in order to register the service immediately

```
SQL> alter system register;

System altered.
```

and restart pluggable database

```
SQL> alter pluggable database pdb close immediate;

SQL> alter pluggable database pdb open;

SQL> exit;
```

then start listener

```
[oracle@ol8-19 ~]$ lsnrctl start
```

and recheck listener's current status

```
[oracle@ol8-19 ~]$ lsnrctl status
```

which should start within a half minute.

Comment: `alter session set container=pdb;` gives `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02248: invalid option for ALTER SESSION`

Comment: I told ignore this part(related to pluggable DB) @Moeez presuming your DB is just a single instance and non-pluggable, isn't it? Just set local listener, and then restart the listener from the command line after logging out the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way :

LISTENER_TST =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol8-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1522))
)
)
)

SID_LIST_LISTENER_TST =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
(SID_NAME = PDB)
(ORACLE_HOME = YOURORACLEHOME)
)
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).