# Cannot connect to a database in SQLDeveloper, I/O error: Network Adapter could not stablish the connection

Tags: oracle, listener, sqlplus, tnsnames, oracle18c

I'm trying to connect to a local database in a computer (from someone else in fact) with Windows Pro and after a long time trying I finnaly installed SQL Express Edition and SQLDeveloper in the 64-bit version.

After the installation finished in the SQL Express Edition I was asked to write a password and got the following information for the database:

> multitenant container database: localhost:1521
>
> Connection database: localhost:1521/XEPDB1
>
> EM Express URL: https://localhost:5500/em

And when I tried to connect in the SQLDeveloper I got **"I/O Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"**

The tsnames.ora file is:

```
#tsnames.ora Network Configuration file: C:\app\OLIVER\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
#Generated by Oracle configuration tools

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SID = CLRExtProc)
         (PRESENTATION = RO)
      )
    )
```

and my listener.ora file is:

```
#listener.ora Network Configuration file: C:\app\OLIVER\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
#Generated by Oracle configuration tools

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\OLIVER\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\OLIVER\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )
    
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = URIEL-PC)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

In the listener, there is a HOST called "Uriel-PC" and actually I don't know any Uriel but I figured that since I've got the Express Edition right from the Oracle page it should be right, so I wrote the info in the "New Database Connection" window in SQLDeveloper

> Host: URIEL-PC
>
> Port: 1521
>
> SID: CLRExtProc

and I got the error I mention. I also tried changing the Host name in the listener.ora file and in the connection window in SQLDeveloper to localhost (As It was the one I got when installing the SQL Express Edition) and reloading the listener but that gave me the exact same error so I kept the original.

Also, I found a solution to the problem here http://www.rebellionrider.com/sql-developer-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection/ where I should check if the listener was running by trying

```
C:\> lsnrctl status
```

which I tried and got

```
Conectándose a (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=URIEL-PC)(PORT=1521))) ESTADO del LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Versión                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Fecha de Inicio           09-MAR-2021 11:06:16
Tiempo Actividad          0 días 0 hr. 58 min. 57 seg.
Nivel de Rastreo          off
Seguridad                 ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Servicio por Defecto      XE
Parámetros del Listener   C:\app\OLIVER\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Log del Listener          C:\app\OLIVER\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\URIEL-PC\listener\alert\log.xml

Recibiendo Resumen de Puntos Finales...
DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=URIEL-PC)(PORT=1521)))   
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))

Resumen de Servicios... El servicio "CLRExtProc" tiene 1 instancia(s). La instancia "CLRExtProc", con estado UNKNOWN, tiene 1 manejador(es) para este servicio...

El comando ha terminado correctamente
```

(I kept the original output in spanish).

Edit:

The Oracle services running are **OracleOraDB18Home1MTSRecoveryService** and **OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener**.

I tried to change the connection information in SQLDeveloper to:

> Host name: localhost
>
> Port: 1521
>
> Service name: XEPDB1

and now I get "Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor".

In SQLPlus when I try to connect like this

```
sqlplus / nolog
connect sys/pass@localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

I get the same error (ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor).

Comment: It doesn't look like you've started the database itself.

Comment: To be honest I don't know, I just started in the databases world, what should I do or check? @pmdba

Comment: Based on the information you were given after installation (of Oracle XE, not SQL\*Plus XE - SQL\*Plus is a client) your SQL Developer connection should be to localhost port 1521 and service name (not SID - there's a radio button to switch between) XEPDB1. However, `lsnrctl` says that service isn't there, so the database hasn't been started, or it can't register with the listener. Can you check the Oracle service is running, and if so, can you connect directly through SQL\*Plus? The `URIEL-PC` means, I think, that your PC's IP address resolves to that name. Have you rebooted since install?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you, I updated the post. I can see two services from Oracle but I don't know if they are the ones that should be there, and I tried to connect with the information you gave me but now I have ORA-12514 error, in sqlplus I try to connect with user sys and the password but that gives ORA-12560 error. And yes, I have rebooted.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459252/5841306) out for registration while ignoring the parts related to pluggable databases.