# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error; Even after restarting the services on Oracle19c

Tags: database, oracle, service, listener, oracle19c

WHile logging in this is what I am getting

```
C:\> set ORACLE_SID=orcl;
```

[image]

Listener status

[image]

All services are running

[image]

Comment: OracleServiceORCL <> OracleServiceorcl. set ORACLE_SID=ORCL Your database ORCL hasn't contacted the listener for registration. Your service is running, but the database can be in any of these states "SHUTDOWN|NOMOUNT|MOUNT|OPEN". Also have a look in the alert-log. Please translate to Windows: # display the alert log
alog () {
  less ${ORACLE_BASE}/diag/rdbms/$(echo ${ORACLE_SID} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')*/${ORACLE_SID}/trace/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log
}

Comment: perhaps you need to set `local_listener` and **register** the service such as [expressed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458885/how-to-register-pluggable-databasepdb-with-new-created-listener/63459252#63459252)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a tricky problem to solve.
can you test with this command ?

```
set ORACLE_SID=orcl
sqlplus /nolog
connect sys/password as sysdba
```

If this does the trick then check if the TNS_ADMIN environment variable is correctly set.

Comment: @SuperPony - there is no functional difference between 'connect / as sysdba' and 'connect username/pswd as sysdba'.  In fact, making a local connection AS SYSDBA, oracle throws away the 'username/pswd' and simply does os authentication. You might as well do 'connect fubar/thiscannotbecorrect as sysdba'.  Thus, your 'test' proves nothing.