# Cannot resolve ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am trying to figure out how to enable the listener for my pdb in sql developer.  I have a pdb named mydatabase, with schemas created.  I have an application connecting with string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.21.0.2:1521/mydatabase.localdomain
```

I have tried

```
alter session set container mydatabase
alter system set address....
alter system register
```

Is there a way in sql developer to easily fix this?

Below is the output from my lsnrctl:

```
oracle@45a14a439b6e /]$ lsnrctl service mydatabase.localdomain

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 28-AUG-2021 03:12:47

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCLCDB.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:31 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "ORCLCDBXDB.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: 45a14a439b6e, pid: 90>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=45a14a439b6e)(PORT=43969))
Service "ca90769ec9bc014be053020015ac01c1.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:31 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "ca910bc928b70229e053020015acdbee.localdomain" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:31 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: 45a14a439b6e, pid: 90>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=45a14a439b6e)(PORT=43969))
      "DEDICATED" established:10 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orclpdb1.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:31 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "mydatabase.localdomain" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:31 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: 45a14a439b6e, pid: 90>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=45a14a439b6e)(PORT=43969))
      "DEDICATED" established:10 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

---

After repeating the steps from stackoverflow.com/questions/63458885/…

from the app server:

```
root@c6420aec9bfa:/opt/authserver# netcat -v 172.21.0.2 1522
netcat: connect to 172.21.0.2 port 1522 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
root@c6420aec9bfa:/opt/authserver# netcat -v 172.21.0.2 1521
Connection to 172.21.0.2 1521 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

from the oracle server: (no port 1522)

```
tcp        0      0 172.21.0.2:58646        172.21.0.2:1521         ESTABLISHED
.
.
```

lsnrctl status:

```
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=1b73269c0a29)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=1b73269c0a29)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCLCDB.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCLCDBXDB.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ca90769ec9bc014be053020015ac01c1.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ca910bc928b70229e053020015acdbee.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclpdb1.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "mydatabase.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

NOTE: this is a docker environment. docker shows 1521 and 1522 exposed.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458885/how-to-register-pluggable-databasepdb-with-new-created-listener

Comment: @pmda i saw that article and did the steps, except i did the close and open actions in the sql developer gui. and the rest in the workspace console.  I just repeated it again step by step in server cli so as to be precise. what should i see in the lsnrctl service command for that the mydatabase.localdomain? i never saw a port 1522 or 1521

Comment: Why 1522? You have a listener running on 1521 just fine. Is your PDB open? The local_listener parameter of your PDB should be the same as your CDB which will allow it to automatically register itself with the same listener when it’s up.

Comment: I repeated the steps in the suggested link and used 1521 this time, and I have the same error and same lsnrctl output. the lsnrctl output does not show either port, but i can connect to the CDB with sql developer. pdp is open.

Comment: Were you able to connect to the PDB database using sqlplus? If yes, what is the service name that you used?

Comment: i cant tell if it connects. just a blank cursor as if there is a connection, but no prompt or feedback.     sqlplus ts/password@MYDABTABASE  and sqlplus ts/password@mydatabas.localdomain.   same result

Comment: still stuck on this. any other suggestions?