# ORA-12541: TNS: no listener

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, listener, sqlplus, ora-12541

I have a VM in Oracle VM Virtual Box running Windows XP. In this VM, I have install Visual Studio .net 2003 with nhibertante ORM to connect to BBDD Oracle 12.2.

Oracle database is hosts in my physical machine with Windows 11 SO. The network configuration between VM and host that ok, or I suppose it, because the ping network servicio work ok.

In my VM I run a SQL*Plus command interface and I try to connect to Oracle database in the host machine.

I use the follow command: `sqlplus user/pass@service`
Well, the error I receive is:

```
ORA-12541: TNS: no listener
```

Maybe some configuration in `listener.ora` or `tnsname.ora` not be ok, but I tried modify several parameter but it didn't work.

My `tnsname.ora` in VM is:

```
`LISTENER = 
 (ADDRESS = 
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = 192.168.56.7)
    (PORT = 1521)
  )


orcl = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
    ADDRESS = 
      our text`(PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = 192.168.56.7)
      (PORT = 1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
`
```

My `listener.ora` in my host machine is:

```
`SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\orclDiego\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\orclDiego\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.56.7)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
`
```

Comment: You might check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458885/how-to-register-pluggable-databasepdb-with-new-created-listener/63459252#63459252) out

Comment: You might also check to ensure that port 1521 on your WIndows 11 host isn't blocked by the system firewall.