# How to fix 'TNS:no listener' error when connecting to Oracle 19c using lsnrctl and tnsping

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am getting issue while finding listener.
Below are the status

when I did "**lsnrctl status**"

```
C:\Users\rk250>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 03-JUN-2023 20:17:24

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

When I did "**tnsping orcl**"

```
C:\Users\rk250>tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 03-JUN-2023 20:18:35

Copyright (c) 1997, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
E:\Oracle19c\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

My db folder structure looks as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZjLt.png)

Comment: Did you *start* the listener service?

Comment: or you might need to set local_listener like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459252/5841306)